# JBoss EAP 6.2 JMX Server and Registry Bindings

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I am currently trying to configure JMX Susbsystem on JBoss EAP 6.2 to help monitor my web application.

Having setup the console I have been unable to figure out what should go in the Server/Registry binding fields as per the following screenshot:

[image: JBoss Admin Console]

I have tried putting in 127.0.0.1:9999 for local host but I get the error:

[image]

Could anyone suggest what these values should be?

Answer (score 0):

Those binding params are out-of-date - they were used with subsystem `jmx:1.0` (JBoss AS 7.0). In that version, correct binding values were socket-binding names ([see example configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/JMX+subsystem+configuration)).

JBoss AS 7.3 (so EAP 6.2 also) with subsystem `jmx:1.3` uses `remoting-connector` and native management interface as a port. For standalone mode no additional configuration is required, domain mode needs additional attribute for `remoting-connector` in domain.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
   <show-model value="true"/>
   <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="false"/>
</subsystem>
```

Step-by-step tutorial is available on [JBoss dev wiki](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJconsoleToConnectToJMXOnAS7), however, from personal experience, be prepared for several problems with connection to server running on remote host.